# Align check boxes on the same row using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, layout, angularjs-material

I am using bootstrap 3 modal, where i am generating checkboxes dynamically . It works fine. I need to align the checkboxes on the same row. So i have used

```
 <div class="row" >                           
     <div   ng-repeat="item in selectedFields">
          <md-checkbox ng-model="checkbox"  class="col-xs-12" aria-label={{item.name}}>
          {{item.name}}
     </md-checkbox>
     </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the class which you have used in the `md-checkbox` tag. You have provided `class="col-xs-12"` as the class and then it will allocate the entire row to display that specific component. Update the class to `col-xs-3` (4 in a row) or `col-xs-4` (3 in a row) and you will get it inline.

Apart from that, there is another approach you can use to get it working.

Following is a simple `form-input` example, and you can update it according to your requirements.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Form control: inline checkbox</h2>
  <form>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="">Option 3
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope it works

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

was it because you were using col-xs-12 instead of col-xs-4

```
<div class="row" >                           
 <div   ng-repeat="item in selectedFields">
      <md-checkbox ng-model="checkbox"  class="col-xs-4" aria-label={{item.name}}>
      {{item.name}}
 </md-checkbox>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you please improve this answer by explaining how you changed the code from the question?